# Right way to escape JSON data from django template

Tags: javascript, django, json, django-templates, django-views

I want to pass a dictionary from django view to a javascript file. The dictionary is built from a database populated by site users. What's the difference between these 2 methods in terms of security?

1. `var mydata = JSON.parse("{{mydata|escapejs}}");`
2. `var mydata = {{ mydata|safe }};`

Further, the [doc at django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#escapejs) says this for `escapejs` : *This does not make the string safe for use in HTML*. Could you show me an example of how it's unsafe & how can I make it safe.

Comment: https://djangosnippets.org/search/?q=json+filter

Comment: Can you elaborate on what kind of data will be used? text, numbers, dates, (un)parsed, (un)sanitized, etc.?

Comment: It's a mix of text & numbers. It's user input that needs to be treated with caution. E.g. `{'fruit':['apple','banana'], 'servings':'2'}`

Answer (score 5):

For anyone coming across this in 2019, Django now provides a third option with the `|json_script` template filter. This filter takes care of properly serializing and escaping your Python object for use in HTML.

From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#json-script), using example data with unsafe characters `my_data = {'hello': 'world</script>&amp;'}`:

```
{{ my_data|json_script:"my-data" }}
```

renders to

```
<script id="my-data" type="application/json">
    {"hello": "world\\u003C/script\\u003E\\u0026amp;"}
</script>
```

You can then access this data in Javascript via

```
var value = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('my-data').textContent);
```

Comment: Is also available outside a template-tag as `django.utils.html.json_script()`

Comment: I woret a post explaining json_script in more detail: https://adamj.eu/tech/2020/02/18/safely-including-data-for-javascript-in-a-django-template/

Answer (score 2):

The following dictionary can break your page without proper escaping:

```
{'x':'</script><b>HELLO</b>'}
```

Inside  tags, you can `json.dumps` it in your view and then use `escapejs` to stay safe.

(I believe the explanation means that if you want to show the output of `json.dumps` in HTML, let's say in a `<pre>` tag, just make sure it is escaped by not using `safe` or `escapejs`.)