# How to display a Python list of strings that contains HTML and JavaScript in a template with JS

Tags: javascript, python, json, django

I have a python list that contains a list of strings. Those strings contain HTML and JavaScript. Right now, I am using `sentences = json.dumps(l)` in Django view, then in the template I use `{{sentences|safe}}`, it works for some strings, but it breaks on the strings that contain lots of HTML and JavaScript. How do I fix this problem?

Thank you for your help.

I tried `JSON.parse(sentences), {{sentences|escapejs}}, {{escape|safe}}`

```py
# in django view
sentences = json.dumps(l)
return render(request, 'detail.html', {
    'sentences': sentences
  })
```

```
// in template, attempt to pass the jsonified python list to js array
var random = {{sentences|safe}};


SyntaxError: "" literal not terminated before end of script 73:78:35396
SyntaxError: unexpected token: identifier
73:78:12
SyntaxError: unexpected token: identifier
73:78:4
SyntaxError: unexpected token: identifier
73:78:20
SyntaxError: unexpected token: identifier
73:78:20
```

Answer (score 1):

The third argument of `render` is *context*, which is a dictionary of variables that you want to access on your template.

In your code, you are setting `context={}`, which means `sentences` isn't being passed to your view.  Try doing this instead:

```
sentences = json.dumps(l)
context = { 
    'sentences': sentences
}
return render(request, 'detail.html', context)
```

Now you should be able to access `sentences` on your template:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var someVar = {{ sentences | safe }} #don't use "random" since that is a keyword
</script>
```

Note that I included `<script>` tags around the `someVar` declaration.  Your code would render as plaintext otherwise.

Comment: Sentences are correctly being passed from the view to the template, and the assignment is enclosed by a script tag. It works for many different types of sentences, except the ones that contain HTML and JavaScript in them. For those sentences, there is an error.

Comment: @atomixx can you show me the result of `print(sentences)` in your view?

Comment: @atomixx, also I assume `sentences` is user generated input?  From my understanding, the purpose of `|safe` is to clean the data of any potential html/javascript that was maliciously inserted by a user, which is not what you want in this case.

Comment: If I don't use |safe (i.e. {{sentence}}), then I get the following error: 

SyntaxError: expected expression, got '&'

Comment: Here is the result of print(sentences) in the view:

["<html>", "<head>", "  <title>Multiplication Table</title>", "  <script type=\"text/javascript\">", "    var rows = prompt(\"How many rows for your multiplication table?", "\");", "    var cols = prompt(\"How many columns for your multiplication table?", "\");", "    if(rows == \"\" || rows == null)", "   \t\t rows = 10;", "    if(cols== \"\" || cols== null)", "   \t\t cols = 10;", "    createTable(rows, cols);", "    function createTable(rows, cols)", "    {", "      var j=1;"]

Comment: I have omitted some elements at the end because of the size

Comment: Few questions:  are you getting the error from terminal or is the error On your browser, also how are you generating sentences?

Comment: I suspect that this code will leave you vulnerable to XSS, but that depends on how it’s generated

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21367480/right-way-to-escape-json-data-from-django-template this solved my problems var my_data = JSON.parse('{{my_data|safe|escapejs}}');. thank you for your help